# Stop append deleting string variable when click to add more objects string list

Tags: python, scripting

This may be a simple thing to do but this what I have got

```
import bpy

selection_names = []

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    selection_names.append(obj.name)
        
print(selection_names)
```

it comes up with `['Cube.001', 'Cube.004', 'Cube.004', 'Cube.007', 'Cube.008', 'Cube.009']`

if I do it again without selecting objects it comes up with this

`[ ]`

As if I hadn't added anything to the `selection_names`.
I'd like it to add more objects when I select more objects

Comment: it is exactly right as you describe it. If you select objects, they will be printed if you run your script. If you don't select anything, it will print [] - which means, the list is empty because you didn't select anything. Maybe you wanna change/improve your question what you really mean!?

Comment: or maybe you wanna delete selection_names = [] because this resets your list.

Comment: Your code is clearing `selection_names = []` every time you run it.